# base case for recursive quicksort on singly linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, list, recursion, quicksort

I'm trying to get my head around a recursive quicksort on a singly linked list. What is the base case, and what do I need to do when I reach it in order for the function to 'rewind' and print a sorted list? Here is some code, but I think it's desperately wrong...

```
public static void qSort(SLLNode first, SLLNode last)
{
    SLLNode pivot = first ;
    SLLNode head = pivot.succ ;
    if (first!=last)
    {   
        while (head!=null)
        {
            if (head.data.compareToIgnoreCase(pivot.data)<0)
            {
                pivot.succ = head.succ ;
                head.succ = first ;
                first = head ;
                qSort(first, pivot) ;
                qSort(head, last) ;
            }
            qSort(first, pivot) ;
            qSort(head, last) ;
            }
        }
}
```

To rephrase my question: **When I reach the base case `first==last`, what do I need to do?** How can I make the recursion rewind and produce the sorted list?

Here's my updated code:

```
public static void qSort(SLLNode first, SLLNode last)
    {
        if (first==last)
        {
            return ;
        }
        SLLNode pivot = first ;
        SLLNode head = pivot.succ ;

        while (head!=null)
        {
            if (head.data.compareToIgnoreCase(pivot.data)<0)
            {
                pivot.succ = head.succ ;
                head.succ = first ;
                first = head ;
                qSort(first, pivot) ;
                qSort(head, last) ;
            }
            qSort(first, pivot) ;
            qSort(head, last) ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

### In General

For a general review on quick-sort, you should probably review the [quick-sort algorithm on Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version). In short, it's easier if you use a `partition` helper function to get your list into a state where everything less than your pivot point is to the left of it, and everything greater than the pivot point is to the right of it. You then call quick-sort recursively with both sides of the pivot.

EJP also has a very good point. I haven't seen quick-sort on a linked list.

### Let's Do It Anyway

The way I see a quick-sort with a linked-list, the algorithm would be something like

```
def qsort(head, tail)
    if head == tail
        return
    pivot = tail
    current = head
    while current != pivot
        if current.value < pivot.value
            move/prepend current to head of the list
        else
            move/append current to tail of the list
        current = current.next
    qsort(head, pivot-1)
    qsort(pivot, tail)
```

It gets a little tricky because you have to keep track of `pivot - 1`, which isn't very natural to do with a singly linked list. Also, the above algorithm doesn't really account for elements that are equal. But the general idea is that you end up with everything less than `pivot` being before it, and everything greater than it being after, and then you call `qsort` again for both sides.

### Your Code

Let's run through your program with a simple case.

```
A->B->C->D
F        L
```

Is our start.

```
SLLNode pivot = first ;
SLLNode head = pivot.succ ;
```

Gives us

```
A->B->C->D
F  H     L
P
```

Let's say `if (head.data.compareToIgnoreCase(pivot.data)<0)` is true for each element given the current state of the list.

So we enter the `if` statement, and do

```
pivot.succ = head.succ ;

A->C->D  B->C
F     L  H
P

head.succ = first ;

B->A->C->D
H  F     L
   P 

first = head ;

B->A->C->D
H  P     L
F
```

This gives us

```
A->B->C->D
F  H     L
P

B->A->C->D  
H  P     L
F
```

If I have that right, then the call to

```
qSort(head, last);
```

Should probably instead be

```
qSort(pivot, last);
```

So you're not calling `qSort` over the whole list again. It also seems like you might want to instead keep going through your list until everything that is less than the pivot is to the left of it, before recursively calling `qSort`.

Comment: @Baba yes I somewhat misspoke. Updated my answer to hopefully be more useful.

Comment: yes i know the array version. much simpler. i tried the partition as in arrays but it seemed even more tricky. eventually i thought of a straight recursion and i have the feeling that i'm quite close now. lack of experience

Comment: @Baba Updated with more analysis. I hope that's helpful and I got it right :)

Answer (score 2):

Investigating Quicksort for a linked list is a useful thing. In studying any algorithm it is important to understand what is absolutely required.

In the case here one discovers that random access iterators are not required. Indeed forward iterators are sufficient.
A lot of Stepanov's work with the STL was to distill such information.

Here is a simple implementation in C++. Sorry for the change of language.
I'm just swapping data instead of node pointers. Doing the latter has nothing to do with Quicksort.

And yes, I know my choice of pivot element can cause problems.
One could find the distance, d, between first and last and then pick a random number x in the range [0, d). Now advance a pointer initialized to first x times, and swap its data with the data pointed to by first.

```
struct Node
{
    Node(int d) : data(d), next(0) {}
    ~Node() { delete next; }
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

void Quicksort(Node* first, Node* last)
{
    if (first == last)
    {
        return;
    }

    Node* pivot = first;
    Node* boundary = first;
    for (Node* it = first->next; it != last; it = it->next)
    {
        // Invariant:
        // The iterators in the range [first, boundary->next) 
        // point to nodes with data less than the pivot
        // element's.
        // The iterators in the range [boundary->next, it) 
        // point to nodes with data greater or equal to 
        // the pivot element's.

        if (it->data < pivot->data)
        {
            // Swap the data to maintain the invariant
            boundary = boundary->next;
            std::swap(it->data, boundary->data);
        }
    }

    // Put the pivot data in its right place
    std::swap(pivot->data, boundary->data);

    Quicksort(first, boundary);
    Quicksort(boundary->next, last);
}
```

The initial call would be something like

```
Quicksort(head, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

The base case is a list with 0 or 1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "rewind."  When you make a recursive call, it goes back up the recursion stack when the call finishes.

`if(first==last) return;`

Comment: Probably you need to check for the base case where the list is empty, so that would become `if(first==last || first==null) return;`

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, note that in a base case where `first==last`, you have a linked list of one element and thus it is already sorted.

I think your algorithm may be slightly off?. You want a loop that moves everything less than the pivot to the first half, and everything greater to the second half. Then (after the loop is done!) you can recursively sort the halves. I see that yours is doing it a little differently, but I'm not convinced it's right....

Finally, as stated by others, sorting a linked list is not a very useful task. You wouldn't use a bike to tow a trailer....